# Why is Instruments preventing objc_msgSend crash

Tags: cocoa, instruments

I have a crash from releasing an object too many times and calling it after it has been released. When I run with instruments, it doesn't crash.

Any Ideas why this might happen?

Im running Lion with Xcode 4 btw.

Comment: Is your application using multithreading in any way?  A timing-related crash could be disrupted by the slight bit of extra load that Instruments places on your device, as well as halts created by things like the Leaks instrument.  Also, is NSZombie being enabled when you run under Instruments?

Comment: It is multithreaded. Timing huh? I will see what I can find out. Yeah, NSZombie is enabled. I am running the Zombie instrument and that gets enabled by default. I did double check as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had Garbage Collection ON for release mode and OFF for debug mode. I set my Analyze Run settings to release so GC was properly retaining and releasing when running Instruments, but debugging there was no GC.